# ionic failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs, ionic-framework

While I'm having an ionic app with AngularJS and trying to use it on a real device I get the following output:

```
    2015-07-06 17:00:15.760 MyApp[2195:832165] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D7596A9C-B658-454C-8418-9A61B26091C2/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
    2015-07-06 17:00:15.803 MyApp[2195:832165] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.8.0 is starting.
    2015-07-06 17:00:15.804 MyApp[2195:832165] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
    2015-07-06 17:00:15.811 MyApp[2195:832165] Unlimited access to network resources
    2015-07-06 17:00:16.460 MyApp[2195:832165] Resetting plugins due to page load.
    2015-07-06 17:00:16.911 MyApp[2195:832165] Finished load of: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/47769242-72D0-4907-810A-85332D9564AF/MyApp.app/www/index.html#/home
    2015-07-06 17:00:24.247 MyApp[2195:832165] Resetting plugins due to page load.
    2015-07-06 17:00:24.259 MyApp[2195:832165] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
    2015-07-06 17:04:08.907 MyApp[2195:832165] Resetting plugins due to page load.
    2015-07-06 17:04:08.910 MyApp[2195:832165] Failed to load webpage with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)
    2015-07-06 17:06:19.397 MyApp[2195:832165] Received memory warning. // Here the the app crashes
```

index.html looks like:

```
  <body ng-app="myapp.module">
    <ion-pane ng-controller="HomeCtrl" ng-init="check()">
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">My ionic app</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="home-content">
        <div class="welcome-message"> Welcome, <span ng-if="!userInfo.isAuthenticated">{{guest}}</span> <span ng-if="userInfo.isAuthenticated">{{userInfo.profile.name}}</span> !</div>

        <button type="button" class="button center-block button-positive" ng-show="userInfo.isAuthenticated" ng-click="logout()" name="button">{{logOutTextButton}}</button>
        <button type="button" class="button center-block button-positive" ng-hide="userInfo.isAuthenticated" ng-click="login()" name="button">{{loginTextButton}}</button>

      </ion-content>
      <footer>Footer text</footer>
    </ion-pane>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error code "999", it looks like you are loading or reloading a second  url before the UIWebView finished loading the first url...

therefore, the system cancelled the first one and is trying to load the second url you passed to it...

Comment: The thing was to run each time `ionic build ios` in my case, meaning that each time I have to compile my ionic code. I though that it refreshes and I only have to build the Xcode project.

Comment: @Subbu Is there anyway to determine which URLs are trying to be loaded?  Or which ones are stepping on each other?

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: this is not the solution!

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error with my Cordova App and it took so many hours to realise the root cause.

First thing, I observed that at least "onDeviceReady" event was fired (by putting an alert statement there). So I suspected that it could be any plugin which might be throwing error inside "onDeviceReady". I put all calls to plugin in separate try-catch blocks. This made "onDeviceReady" to be successfully completed and launch app. Finally I also found error logs pointing to one plugin.

Hope this helps someone in future.